# Multiple application domains for Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, deezer

Is there a way to specify multiple domains for the Deezer authentication? Would be helpful to have multiple authentication endpoints (test, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you'll have to create one application ID per domain. However, a good way to start would be to use subdomains. 
For example, you can set example.com as domain on the Deezer developers website, and then use staging.example.com and www.example.com.

Comment: Thanks - we used that fix for now. Would be a nice feature to have in the future however, e.g. to have a single app on localhost + hosted domain, as done for FB apps.

Comment: It's easy and functional to add a `127.0.0.1<-local.example.com` entry to your hosts file (`/private/etc/hosts` file on mac), then don't forget to refresh the cache (`dscacheutil -flushcache` on mac).